# Suppress "[DBG}: PS C:\.path...." on every step when stepping through Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Stepping through a powershell script and finding it very annoying that stepping prints a line in the console on every step. Is there away to suppress this?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the [`prompt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Prompts) function as follows (if you place this at the end of your `$PROFILE` file, it'll take effect in all future sessions, unless [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) loading is situationally disabled):

```
$function:prompt = 'if ($PSDebugContext) { return "" }; ' + $function:prompt
```

*No* prompt is then printed while you're in PowerShell's [debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Debuggers), but you can tweak the `""` value as needed.